# How to change path fill color for Kendo bar / line chart?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Click here for demo - https://dojo.telerik.com/@rikinshah/EQiMupoG

I have lots of  elements for navigation in headers and icon buttons in footer. all of them are using svg > path elements. 
I want to change color for all path elements except Kendo Chart which also contains path elements.

In css I use this to make all to use same color :

```
path {
    fill: #4b4c4c
}
```

but this also changes color for Kendo chart background.

I tried using :not selector for div ID to fill path for kendo and also tried

```
chartArea: {
                background: "#4b4c4c",
            }, 
path: {
fill: "#4b4c4c"},
fill: {
color: "4b4c4c"}
```

none of this changes path for svg element in kendo graph.

```
<div id="kendoChart" class="demo-section k-content wide" style="margin-left: -3px;">
<div id="chart"></div>
</div>


      function createChart() {
                $("#chart").kendoChart({
                    theme: "flat",
                    chartArea: {
                        background: "transparent",
                    },
                    legendItemClick: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "column",
                        width: 90,
                        gap: 1,
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: "bottom",
                        spacing: 15,
                        labels: {
                            font: "12px sans-serif",
                            color: "#7F7F7F"
                        },
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: [parseFloat(($('#room-revenue1').text()).replace(/,/g, "")),
                            parseFloat(($('#room-revenue2').text()).replace(/,/g, "")),
                            parseFloat(($('#room-revenue3').text()).replace(/,/g, "")),
                            parseFloat(($('#room-revenue4').text()).replace(/,/g, "")),
                            parseFloat(($('#room-revenue5').text()).replace(/,/g, "")),
                            parseFloat(($('#room-revenue6').text()).replace(/,/g, "")),
                            parseFloat(($('#room-revenue7').text()).replace(/,/g, "")), ],
                        name: "Room Revenue",
                        color: "#4472c3",
                        width: 500,
                        tooltip: {
                            visible: true,
                            template: "#= series.name #: #= kendo.format('{0:C2}',value) #",
                            font: "12px sans-serif",
                        },
                    }, {
                        type: "line",
                        data: [$('#rooms-sold1').text(),
                            $('#rooms-sold2').text(),
                            $('#rooms-sold3').text(),
                            $('#rooms-sold4').text(),
                            $('#rooms-sold5').text(),
                            $('#rooms-sold6').text(),
                            $('#rooms-sold7').text()],
                        name: "Room Sold",
                        color: "#12ccbe",
                        axis: "Rooms Sold",
                        width: 2,
                        markers: { visible: true },
                        tooltip: {
                            visible: true,
                            template: "#= series.name #: #= value #",
                            font: "12px sans-serif",
                        },
                    }],
                    render: function (e) {
                        var el = e.sender.element;
                        el.find("text:contains(Room Revenue)")
                            .parent()
                            .prev("path")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 3);
                        el.find("text:contains(Room Sold)")
                            .parent()
                            .prev("path")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 0);
                    },
                    valueAxes: [
                        {
                            visible: false,
                            majorGridLines: {
                                visible: true,
                                width: 0.5,
                                dashType: "solid",
                                color: "#ededed"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Rooms Sold",
                            color: "#4e4141",
                            visible: false,
                            line: { visible: false },
                            majorGridLines: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                        }],
                    categoryAxis: {
                        categories: [($('#date1').text()).substring(0, 3),
                        ($('#date2').text()).substring(0, 3),
                        ($('#date3').text()).substring(0, 3),
                        ($('#date4').text()).substring(0, 3),
                        ($('#date5').text()).substring(0, 3),
                        ($('#date6').text()).substring(0, 3),
                        ($('#date7').text()).substring(0, 3)],
                        labels: {
                            font: "12px sans-serif",
                            color: "#7F7F7F"
                        },
                        majorGridLines: {
                            visible: false,
                        },
                    },
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(createChart);
            $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart(), 400);
```

I want to keep kendo chart background color / path fill color unchanged.

Comment: I could not find any specific solution for this where Kendo chart is being used and specific path fill is being excluded.

Comment: How many chart elements are you using? Just one?

Comment: @Shai yes just one chart on this page.

Comment: There is some information here but not sure how to use it and cannot find any example on Kendo website. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/diagram/path/configuration/fill

Comment: Can you add a live demo in dojo.telerik.com ?

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/@rikinshah/EQiMupoG I created a demo here. I fill path with value #4b4c4c for all other svg elements on my page. but I want to exclude my graph from using fill value.